# Inserting dictionary values in pandas column

Tags: python, pandas

C is my column in pandas dataframe(df). And it consists of many lists.

```
          C
  [ab ab bc abb]
  [ll li lo ll]
```

D is my dictionary which is as follows.

```
D={'ab':0, 'bc':1, 'abb':2, 'll':3, 'li':4, 'lo':5}
```

Now, I want to assign the values of my dictionary to the list and for that, I am using the below mentioned code.

```
df.C= [D[item] for item in df.C]
```

Here, I am getting this error:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you have a list of **space separated strings**, so you'll need two loops, not one. Try this instead:

```
df.C = [[D[j] for j in i.split()] for i df.C]
```

If you have to handle missing keys, use `dict.get` instead:

```
df.C = [[D.get(j, -1) for j in i.split()] for i df.C]
```

Where `-1` is some default value.

Comment: @Vic13 hmpphh.. looking at your string that doesnt look that good though. how is lettuce separated from black olives?

Comment: @AntonvBR That's a good point. This input has not been sanitised well.

Comment: Of course, this fine print isn't in the question so I'm wondering if it's worth bothering about.

Comment: Nice solution though, list comprehensions can be more readable than using an apply after str split, another approach I could think of, inn my opinion.